# how to send payload object to rest full web service url from w2ui grid in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, w2ui

I am developing web application by using spring frame work. In my project total Http calls based on rest full web services with status code. My code fine. I implemented jquery http calls for sending payload object to webservice and got json object form web service. it works fine. when coming to w2UI grid, How pass payload object to restfull web services. it there any property for w2ui grid. I searched in google but no answer. I need's add a payload object to w2ui grid. 
I need's add this object to url :

```
var payload = {
  "id":id, 
  "no":no,
};
```

```js
$('#servicesReportwiGrid').w2grid({
  name: 'servicesReportwiGrid',
  header: '<spring:message code="hms.left.reports.opreports.ServicesReport"/>',
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  show: {
    header: true,
    footer: true,
    lineNumbers: true
  },
  columns: [{
      field: 'patientId',
      caption: '<spring:message code="common.module.mrno"/>',
      size: '120px'
    },
    {
      field: 'visitId',
      caption: '<spring:message code="common.module.visitid"/>',
      size: '120px'
    },
    {
      field: 'patientName',
      caption: '<spring:message code="common.module.patient"/>',
      size: '120px'
    },
  ],
  onLoad: function(target, eventData) {
    var serverJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(eventData);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello, the question is tagged with jqGrid. I think that this tag should be removed and changed with the appropriate one - w2ui grid.

Comment: I needs to call pure web services for w2ui gird. is there any solution boss.  is w2grid suitable or not?

Answer (score 0):

To add additional data to a w2grid server request you can modify `w2grid.postData`.

From the [docs](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.postData):

> Adding properties to .postData object will instruct the grid to submit these parameters to the remote data source with each remote request (pull, sort, search, save, delete).

Example:

```
$('#grid').w2grid({
    name    : 'grid',
    url        : 'url/to/server',
    columns: [                
        { field: 'recid', caption: 'ID', size: '50px' },
        { field: 'lname', caption: 'Last Name', size: '30%' },
        { field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name', size: '30%' }
    ],
    postData: {
        param1 : 'value1', 
        param2 : 'value2'
    }
});
```

You can also set the property during runtime:

```
w2ui.grid.postData['myVar'] = 'value';
```

Comment: Thank you boss. I am getting error : add Object { type: "click", execute: "before", target: null, onComplete: null }  w2ui.min.js:3:177
ERROR: Server communication failed. 
   EXPECTED: Object { status: "success", total: 5, records: Array[1] } 
         OR: Object { status: "error", message: "error message" } 
   RECEIVED:

Comment: Rest Controller Code : @RequestMapping(value="/search", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET}, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public ResponseEntity<List<CampaignDTO>> searchcampaign(@RequestBody CampaignDTO dto) {
      List<CampaignDTO> search = campaignService.searchCampaignDetails(dto);
      logger.debug("Rest Controller data :"+search);
      logger.debug("Rest Controller data :"+search.size());
         return new ResponseEntity<List<CampaignDTO>>(search, HttpStatus.OK);
     }

Comment: Looks like your server is not responding with an appropriate answer. I have no idea how you have to write your backend. The data structures are defined here: http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/grid/overview#data-structures and here http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2form.url and here are some backend server examples: https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/tree/master/server (note that the examples are meant for use with version 1.4 and may have to be adapted to work with 1.5).

Comment: The easiest thing would probably be to set the w2ui data type to JSON (``w2utils.settings.dataType = 'JSON';``) and have your server return some hardcoded valid JSON (as expected by w2grid) and then go from there to make it dynamic.

Comment: Where I keep this code : (w2utils.settings.dataType = 'JSON';). sir

Comment: In server side I wrote spring rest full web service. But I din't get response from the w2grid